# How to atomically compare and set different variables?

Tags: java, concurrency

When I want to compare-and-set on a single variable, it is fairly straightforward:

```
enum State {ON, OFF, BROKEN};
AtomicReference<State> state = new AtomicReference<>(State.OFF);

void turnOn() { state.compareAndSet(State.OFF, State.ON); }
```

However, if I want to compare on one variable and set another, then I have to use some other locking mechanism:

```
enum Direction {LEFT, RIGHT};
State state;
Direction direction;

void turnOn() {
  synchronized(state) {
    if (state == state.OFF) state = State.ON
  }
}

void pointLeft() {
  synchronized(state) {
    if (state == State.ON) {
      direction = Direction.LEFT;
    }
  }
}
```

This kind of solution is necessary if I need `state` to remain "On" the whole time while doing my critical section. It's fine for other threads to read the state, but the important part is for it not to change.

In this example, the "point left" code is fairly quick, but in my actual application the synchronized block would be potentially much larger. Additionally, it causes me to include synchronization in the trivial `turnOn` method instead of using existing compare-and-set logic.

Comment: If you need to synchronise then you need to synchronise. If no thread can read the values while you are changing them, then that's the requirement. You cannot change this. Or is there some other requirement?

Comment: Other threads can read, but should not write. I'll clarify in the question.

Comment: [`ReentrantReadWriteLock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html). No?

Comment: Is this for modeling turn signals? Perhaps creating a state machine with synchronized transitions would lead to the simplest solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either create a synchronized method that does both state changes, or create an immutable class an instance of which represents the dual state and use an AtomicReference for that:

```
public class DirectionState {
    private final Direction direction;
    private final State state;
    // rest of class omitted
}


private AtomicReference<DirectionState> ref = new AtomicReference<>(new DirectionState(Direction.LEFT, State.OFF));
```

and use it for changing the fields individually:

```
// locking code removed
void turnOn() {
    DirectionState directionState = ref.get();
    directionState.compareAndSet(directionState, new DirectionState(directionState.getDirection(), State.ON));
}
// similar for pointLeft()
```

and together

```
void set(Direction direction, State state) {
    ref.set(new DirectionState(direction, state));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second code sample will not work. You are synchronizing on the member variable that you are changing. This means that different threads are potentially (likely?) obtaining different locks. This means the code is not safe at all.

You could either use a `Lock` or another immutable object to synchronized on.

```
enum Direction {LEFT, RIGHT};
private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
State state;
Direction direction;

void turnOn() {
  lock.lock();
  try {
    if (state == state.OFF) state = State.ON
  } finally {
    lock.unlock();
  }
}

void pointLeft() {
  lock.lock();
  try {
    if (state == State.ON) {
      direction = Direction.LEFT;
    }
  } finally {
    lock.unlock();
  }
}
```

Comment: In this version, `state` could remain an `AtomicReference` and `turnOn` would not require locking, right?

Comment: Is this approach where the full method body is locked any different from keyword synchronized methods?

Comment: @MickMnemonic It really depends on what other methods exist in the class which read state and direction. If there are other methods which assume that direction cannot change while state is not ON, then any reads or mutations of both state and direction must be synchronized.

Comment: @MikeD the only difference is that anyone synchronizing on an instance of this object would not be blocking the pointLeft, or turnOn methods.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as posted in your question does not require any atomic modification as there is no atomic read of both values that could be affected by the atomicity of the modification.

Let’s look at the two methods (after fixing your bug of using a mutable variable’s content as mutex):

```
void turnOn() {
  synchronized(this) {
    if (state == state.OFF) state = State.ON
  }
}

void pointLeft() {
  synchronized(this) {
    if (state == State.ON) {
      direction = Direction.LEFT;
    }
  }
}
```

regarding concurrent invocations of `turnOn()` there will be no difference in the outcome. If *both* methods are invoked concurrently, there are two scenarios:

1. a thread manages to complete the `synchronized` block of `turnOn()` before the `synchronized` block of `pointLeft()` will be entered
2. all attempts of `pointLeft()` complete their `synchronized` block before a thread enters the `synchronized` block of `turnOn()`

In either case, the `state` variable will contain the value `State.ON` afterwards if at least one thread invoked `turnOn()` (assuming that the state wasn’t `BROKEN`) and `direction` will either be changed to `Direction.LEFT` or left untouched based on either, the unpredictable thread timing or inter-thread dependencies outside the scope of this class.

Now what would happen if we use the `AtomicReference` as in your first version?

```
final AtomicReference<State> state = new AtomicReference<>(State.OFF);
void turnOn() { state.compareAndSet(State.OFF, State.ON); }
void pointLeft() { if(state.get() == State.ON) direction = Direction.LEFT; }
```

`AtomicReference.get` is an atomic operation, so in a concurrent scenario we still have only two possible scenarios:

1. An invocation of `compareAndSet` completed successfully before `get`
2. No invocation of `compareAndSet` completed successfully before `get`

And in either case, since `turnOn` doesn’t change `state`, it will contain `State.ON` if at least one thread invoked `turnOn()` when its previous state was `State.OFF`.

So the outcome is exactly the same and we don’t need to use `synchronized` blocks here. If `pointLeft()` is a more complex method and accesses the `state` multiple times, you can simply read the value once at the beginning:

```
void pointLeft() {
  State currentState = state.get();
  if(currentState == State.ON) {
    direction = Direction.LEFT;
  //   possibly more code, may use currentState
  }
  // possibly more code, may use currentState
}
```

Now the `state` is still read atomically and the method will act accordingly. Other threads modifying the `state` may overlap with the subsequent execution of `pointLeft()` but since `pointLeft()` doesn’t touch `state` ever again, this potential overlapping has no effect, thus, the method will behave as if being atomically regarding the `state` variable without actually blocking threads.

Note that if there are other reasons to use mutexes, i.e. because of the other shared variables, you may still combine `synchronized` with the atomic variable:

```
final AtomicReference<State> state = new AtomicReference<>(State.OFF);
void turnOn() {
  state.compareAndSet(State.OFF, State.ON);
}
void pointLeft() {
  synchronized(this) { // no concurrent pointLeft() execution
    State currentState = state.get();
    if(currentState == State.ON) {
      direction = Direction.LEFT;
      //   possibly more code, may use currentState
    }
    // possibly more code, may use currentState
  }
}
```

`turnOn()` still won’t be blocked and thus we have to ensure that other methods read the `state` exactly once and act as-if-atomic regarding that `state` while being really atomic regarding all other code synchronizing on the same mutex.